# Geckodriver not starting on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, selenium, geckodriver

I've written **Java 8 + GUI in Swing + Selenium 3.0.0-beta** (to get some data from web) application (IDE: Intellij Idea), exported to **.jar** - it works correctly on Windows 10, Windows 7 with JRE installed. Unfortunately **i have to start it on Mac** - it launches, but error appears:

```
IllegalStateException - geckodriver not executable.
```

I found a clue to add in my project:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path");
```

but **it doesn't work with either geckodriver.exe nor geckodriver for Mac**.
Can You provide any solution or workaround to that problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you were getting, it does not have the appropriate permissions.

> IllegalStateException - geckodriver not executable.

Open up a terminal in the Mac, and execute this:

```
$ chmod +x geckodriver
```

and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Rely on [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to handle the proper geckodriver for your platform (Mac OS X):

```
FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```